# Do I have to cut y (prediction) column from Pandas dataframe with Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've split my Pandas DataFrame into `train_X` and `train_y` parts, where `train_X` has all N columns, and `train_y` has only N-th column, depicting the variable that I want to predict. Currently I'm doing:

```
train_X.drop("N-th column name", axis=1, inplace=True)
model = SomeSklearnModel()
model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Do I have to do it "by hand" (i. e. using `drop()` on `train_X`), or can I just do the 3rd line and Scikit-learn will "know" which column `train_y` is and not use it for model training (only for checking results)?

Comment: I recommend using sklearns [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), but to answer your question, yes, you will have to remove the answer column.

Comment: @BenPap I've split my data with it, yes. But AFAIK it does not affect columns, which is my primary concern here.

Comment: Generally before `train_test_split` you could do `y = X.pop('nth column name')` - `pop` both drops and returns the column values for assignment

Comment: @ChrisA but is it any different than my approach? I mean, I still have to do it by hand. It's a useful thing when I'm using this for more than one model, which is useful, though.

Comment: Yes, whichever way you do it, you'll need to declare `X` and `y` explicitly

Comment: @ChrisA I see now! I misunderstood your code in my previous answer, that's really clever. Please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare `X` and `y` explicitly when calling `fit` on a `sklearn` estimator. Generally by the time you're ready to split your data into training and testing sets, `X` should include model features only, so should not include your target `y`.
There are many ways to do it, but here a couple of common ways using the iris dataset as an example:

```
# Setup
df_iris = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': [5.0, 4.8, 5.8, 5.7, 4.5, 6.0, 6.3, 4.8, 5.6, 6.4],
                        'sepal_width': [3.2, 3.4, 2.8, 4.4, 2.3, 3.0, 2.5, 3.4, 3.0, 2.8],
                        'petal_length': [1.2, 1.6, 5.1, 1.5, 1.3, 4.8, 5.0, 1.9, 4.5, 5.6],
                        'petal_width': [0.2, 0.2, 2.4, 0.4, 0.3, 1.8, 1.9, 0.2, 1.5, 2.1],
                        'target': ['setosa', 'setosa', 'virginica', 'setosa', 'setosa','virginica',
                                   'virginica', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']})
```

If your target `y` is the "n-th" column of "n", you can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) slicing:

```
X = df_iris.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df_iris.iloc[:, -1]
```

Another way would be to use [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) which both drops and returns the column for assignment:

```
X = df_iris.copy()
y = X.pop('target')
```

Or using your own method with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
X = df_iris.drop('target', axis=1)
y = df_iris['target']
```